# trying to remove lines containing yellow highlighted text

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have a document that i'm reviewing with yellow highlighted text. i want a macro to go through and remove the lines that are highlighted. so far this is what i have:

```
Sub hilight()
'
' hilight Macro
' removes lines in yellow hi-lighter

Dim p As Paragraph

For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Dim holder As String
    If p.Range.Text = highlighted_text Then
        p.Range.Text = holder
    End If
Next p

End Sub
```

i need to know how highlighted text property is given so i can replace `highlighted_text`

Comment: You can search for text with yellow highlights and replace with nothing using standard search-replace. Or are you particulary looking for a VBA solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Note that it only replaces paragraphs in which the *entire paragraph* is yellow highlighted, not just part of it. There are a few things worth pointing out:

- Replacing a paragraph will also take out the trailing line break, so I include it in the placeholder text
- Since a line break is being added, if you don't loop through the paragraphs backwards, it'll be an infinite loop (thus the step -1)
- Dim all variables outside of a loop

```vb
Sub ReplaceYellowParagrahps()

Dim p As Paragraph
Dim i As Long, count As Long
Dim placeholderText As String
placeholderText = "holder" & vblf

count = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.count

For i = count To 1 Step -1
    With ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range
        If .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then
            .Text = placeholderText
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: As an additional hint, if you turn on the macro recorder and then highlight some text yellow, you'll see the syntax for highlighting (recorder is great for finding out what property is what).